# Displaying local JSON array through search function

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a JSON file of 300 arrays (randomly generated) that I am trying to make searchable via a HTML search input. Structure as follows:

```
{"username":"eshawh","first_name":"Elizabeth","last_name":"Shaw","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Proactive background hierarchy","language":"Nepali"},
{"username":"tromeroi","first_name":"Terry","last_name":"Romero","email":"tromeroi@amazon.co.jp","gender":"Male","sexuality":"Persistent intermediate structure","language":"Swati"},
```

etc.

**2 Questions:**

1. Is it possible to extract data from a local JSON file? or can
   Jquery only operate online? (is there a native JS alternative?)
2. If no and all the arrays have to be within the HTML, what Javascript functions would be useful for searching and displaying based on user input?

So far I have this which has given me some idea of where I should be heading.

```
user=users.find(el=>el.name=="Jack");
for(key in user){
  alert(key+":"+user[key]);
}
```

However it uses some terms I am unfamiliar with. Is there an easier way?

**UPDATED** It cant access a server as the page is part of a game that runs off a specialized C# browser that compiles local HTML pages. It is designed to be played offline.

Comment: store the file on your server and use ajax to retrieve it

Comment: @charlietfl i have updated the question to explain server issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1. Javascript can't access your local file system. It would be a huge security issue. You have to serve that local file with a web server (expressJS, Apache, etc.). Then call the URL where the file is served, load the data in a variable, and then... do whatever with the data... ie: loop thru it to search what you need.
2. I personally use `map`. ie: myArrayVariable.map(function(v,k){ /*code*/ }) (more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

The piece of code you provided is written in ES6. The arrow notation is a quick way to identify it. `=>`

This:

`el=>el.name=="Jack"`

is the same as:

`function(el){ return el.name == "Jack" }`

**UPDATED**: Since you have a C# script compiling your code, I suggest to look into file system functions available to your specific C# compiler. My experience is with NodeJS, and I'm thinking about something like  https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback but for C#.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the question to include the reason why I cant use a server. 
This is a huge help, Will this mean that all the JSON data will have to be a variable within the HTML?

Comment: Yes, the JSON data has to be loaded (somehow... ajax pinging a remote server, or nodeJS `fs` reading a file) for JS to work with it

Comment: so something like: var users = [{"username":"jhall0","first_name":"Jean","last_name":"Hall","email":"jhall0@loc.gov","gender":"Female","sexuality":"Innovative empowering budgetary management","language":"Punjabi"}, etc wouldn't work if it was placed in the html? I would much rather sort this out without the use of the C# compiler as my C# is even worse than my Javascript. Is there another type of data (CSV for instance) that CAN be loaded or read by js?

Comment: yes, that would work if placed directly in your JS block. I believe the issue you are having is making your JSON available to JS. JSON is the easiest to work with. Solve that issue... and you'll be able to move forward with your code

Comment: Thanks! having the massive block of JSON as a variable in the code isn't a problem. the search function is only being used fleetingly so as long as i can directly reference it easily then i'm fine.

Comment: @gezer4000 just assign it to a javascript variable then if the data is static

Comment: @charlietfl so: <script type='text/javascript> var users = [{"blah blah blah arrays"}] </script> works?